# paintComponent interleaved with previous method

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm having the following structure:

```
method1
method2
...
methodn

methodX
```

method x contains:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new CanvasBoard(tree));

frame.setSize(1200, 600);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I have several `System.out.println` in `method1`...`methodn` and in `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` of `CanvasBoard`.

I get the messages interleaved, how can I solve that?

Comment: Make sure the UI is created and modified only from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Comment: Let me understand better: you call _method1_ and then _method2_ and then _method3_ and so on until _methodn_. Then you call _methodx_. That's right?

Comment: Yes, although the methods are called sequentially, the methodx messages are interleaved with messages from previous methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing runs within it's own thread, which is different from the thread which launches your program.

This means that the component is been painted within a different thread then you code is likely been run.

Even if all you're code is running within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, `paintComponent` could be called at any time, meaning that the messaging will be different on each run.

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.

Make sure that you start and run your UI code from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread....

Answer (score 1):

Add thread info to your print outs to see if there are multiple threads running through your code

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread() + ": <your log message here>");
```